# Toggling Icons in Tabs in subheader

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to be Toggling b/w two icons. For ex: When i clicked on grid icon it will show up grid data and hide List Icon.Again when i clicked on the same icon it will show up List data and hide grid Icon.

Here is my code in Tabs.html

```
 <div menu-toggle="right" ng-hide="data.grid = !data.grid">>
```

And I found             http://codepen.io/mhartington/pen/zxpwbK2            But it's related to Buttons.

Answer (score 1):

At the same time one needs to be show and one needs to be hide,for that u can use ng-show and ng-hide

```
<div menu-toggle="right" ng-hide="data.grid = !data.grid">

for grid:

 <div class="" ng-hide="data.grid = !data.grid">


for icon:

<div class="" ng-show="data.grid = !data.grid">
```

Comment: I think it's wrong.. Icon is not changing and just changing data.. displaying two icons one is list and another grid.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, I think this is what you are expecting.

```
   <ion-view view-title="Icon Sample">
      <ion-header-bar>
        <h1> Icon sample </h1>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content>
       <button class="button button-icon" ng-click="toggleIcon()">
        <i class="icon" ng-class="isToggled ? 'ion-ios-list-outline' : 'ion-grid'"></i>
        {{buttonText}}</button>
     </ion-content>
   </ion-view>
```

and the controller code as follows:

```
    .controller('sampleCtrl', function($scope){
     $scope.isToggled = true;
     $scope.buttonText = 'List';
     $scope.toggleIcon = function(){
     if($scope.isToggled){
       $scope.isToggled = false;
       $scope.buttonText ='Grid';
     }
    else{
     $scope.isToggled = true;
     $scope.buttonText ='List';
   }
 }
});
```

http://codepen.io/svswaminathan/pen/ByPKgp

Check out this codepen example to see if it fits your requirement.This has just the code to toggle the icon alternatively within a button. I believe you are able to load the data appropriately already

Comment: yeah.thank you. But data is not showing. and u mentioned button. But my requirement is not for buttons.For Icons in Tabs

Comment: I need another requirement.         Actually I am working on project.Header have two buttons called sign-in and sign-up button.so after successful sign-in it will show like disable sign-in button and hiding sign-up button.   Do you know about that?

Comment: can u post code sample for the issue you are facing ?

Comment: I want to show toggle Icons in Tabs not in buttons. This is my tabs.html `<div ng-if="toggle!=true"><ion-tab title="List View" icon-off="ion-grid" icon-on="ion-grid"  href="#/tab/Movies">
<ion-nav-view name="tab-listView"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab> </div> 
  
 <div ng-if="toggle==true"> 
        <ion-tab title="List View" icon-off="ion-navicon" icon-on="ion-navicon" href="#/tab/list">  <ion-nav-view name="tab-listView"></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-tab></div>`

Comment: In Movies controller I mentioned $scope.toggle=true;  In List controller mentioned false

Comment: You are using two different controllers and two scope variables so turning on/off in one will not be reflected in the other. Can you explain more on what is the actual requirement? do you want to have two tabs one to show the list view and one to show the grid view for the same data ?

Comment: Yes, I want to have two tabs but one(grid) should hide and one should(list) visible, one to show the list and when i click on the same tab it should show grid data and should hide tab.